# Node JS POST | PUT body validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

In **production** level environments what is more or less the standard for POST / PUT body validation?

My approach has always been something like:

```
const isValid = (req.body.foo && /[a-z0-9]*/i.test(req.body.foo))
```

Only checking that the variable exists and does not contain unexpected characters.

Comment: Depends on what you're validating. There are libraries that can help you with this, like `joi`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You tagged your question with Express so I'll focus on request body validation in Express. For Express there are two modules used for validation that are most popular:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validation

Both are stable and widely used.
You can use any of them depending on which validation syntax you prefer. The first one is internally using `validator`.
The second one is internally using `joi`.

See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi

Example of `express-validator` usage inside of a route handler:

```
req.checkBody('postparam', 'Invalid postparam').notEmpty().isInt();
req.checkParams('urlparam', 'Invalid urlparam').isAlpha();
req.checkQuery('getparam', 'Invalid getparam').isInt();
```

Example of `express-validation` usage as a middleware

```
validate({body: {
  email: Joi.string().email().required(),
  password: Joi.string().regex(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}/).required()
}})
```

This returns a middleware. That object is often exported as a module and stored in a different file.

Comment: Please! also put code rather than just putting Links.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey I added code examples. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

in production level environnement, it's common to see validation steps as middlewares (using *Express*), and, in general cases, people use validation library or custom modules to match pattern or check objects, so it often looks like the following :

```
import myValidation from '../helpers/validation';
const validateUserBody = (req, res, next) =>  {
  return myValidation(req.body)
           ? next()
           : res.status(400).json({message: "Bad body"})
}
```